# Can I define the following macro "unstringifying" from a static const char* array?

Tags: c++, c, boost, macros, c-preprocessor

I have, in a `.c` file, the following (this is a much smaller array to exemplify):

```
static const char* __someNames[] =
{
    "Fox",
    "Wulf",
    "Cat"
};
```

Then later I am defining a macro like this:

```
#define EXAMPLE(N) XXX
```

where I would like XXX to be replaced by `__someNames[N]` without the `"`..i.e I would like

```
#define EXAMPLE(1)
```

to expand to:

```
Wulf
```

How can I go about this?

**EDIT**

Some cool ideas. This is more out of intellectual curiosity that I want to do this. I like the idea of the #include "file.h# twice with a redefined macro..what if I can also use the boost preprocessor (I added c++ and boost tags to question) - would I be able to get around having the extra "file.h"? The one with a #define per string is also cool though slightly less idea given how many #defines I would have...

Comment: Sounds like a perfect XY question, "I have this problem X, I think the solution is Y, so I'll ask how to do Y".

Comment: why do you want it to expand to wulf?  how are you planning on using it?

Comment: By the way `__` in the beginning of identifiers is reserved for the compiler/C library implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the solution to your X problem (where you have asked about the Y solution) is to turn the thing around and use macros to put the string in, and then use the same macro redefined to do whatever else it is you want to do.

For example:

```
#define EXAMPLE(x)   #x,

static const char* __someNames[] =
{

#include "file.h"
};

#undef EXAMPLE
#define EXAMPLE(x)   x,

enum animals 
{
#include "file.h"
};
```

where file.h contains:

```
EXAMPLE(Fox)
EXAMPLE(Wulf)
EXAMPLE(Cat)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this with the standard C or C++ pre-processor.

The pre-processor scans your code for identifiers, and if an identifier matches a macro, it expands the macro. The expanded macro, in this case, would actually be the array name followed by the input number in brackets.

It is a limitation of the way the pre-processor works!

A work-around is like this...

```
#define EXAMPLE_1  Wolf
#define EXAMPLE_2  Dog
#define EXAMPLE_3  Cat

#define EXAMPLE_X(n) EXAMPLE_##n

// Then say 

EXAMPLE_X(1); // will put Wolf;

int EXAMPLE_X(2) = 0;// expands to int Dog = 0;
```

Unfortunately that only works if you pass in constants like `1` or `2` etc... Variables would not work.

OR ...

```
static const char* __someNames[] =
{
    #define __someNames_1 Fox
    "Fox",
    #define __someNames_2 Wulf
    "Wulf",
    #define __someNames_3 Cat
    "Cat"
};    


#define EXAMPLE_X(n) __someNames_##n
```

That will work the way you expect and keep the same scheme, but it will put a lot of defines for big arrays!.

Answer (score -1):

```
 #define EXAMPLE(_x)  __someNames[(_x)]
```

Comment: How does that remove the quotes around the string in `__someNames`?

Comment: it won't expand to what they are asking for.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: The question asked for how EXAMPLE(1) can turn into an index into the static const char* array __someNames yielding Wulf, which this answer answers. If I've misunderstood the question and it's really about whether you can index into an array of strings and yield an identifier, then the answer is "No. You can't do that in the C preprocessor".

Comment: That leaves a token sequence of __someNames[(1)] after macro expansion.

Comment: @bobshacks: Which inlines to the const string "Wulf".

Comment: as the question is written they want it to expand to Wulf.... so if Wulf was a function you could then use the Macro and call it  (not that its possible using this approach )

Comment: @SecurityMatt - Yes but not to the identifier Wolf. It resolves to a pointer to a const char* literal, not an identifier that the compiler will see as an identifier token.